# Google Adwords Keyword Tool Service

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to know, is it possible to access keyword ideas from Google Ad Words without any developer token. I have my MCC account but not any developer token.

I want to access only the keyword ideas from Google Adwords with only email, password, client ID.

I have done lot of research but found nothing, Do anyone have some idea.
I am developing keyword suggestion tool for my website that need to access keywords from Google Adwords in java technology.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to access the AdWords API without a developer token. Google needs to know who's using it in case they need to contact you, and to ensure you're following their [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/terms). You will have a problem if you apply for a token just for use with the keyword tool because Google requires you to implement a [minimum set of features](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/requirements), and your tool would need to provide the entire list before you would be able to use the keyword tool.